# Value of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{\sqrt{3!!}\cdot \sqrt[3]{5!!} \ldots \sqrt[n]{(2n-1)!!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{\sqrt{3!!}\cdot \sqrt[3]{5!!} \ldots \sqrt[n]{(2n-1)!!}}$$
It turns out that this limit equals $1$.  The solution key uses Stolz-Cesaro theorem and I was wondering if this could be evaluated without this theorem.
The furthest I got to was
$$\ln{L}=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} \ln{\left(2i-1\right)!!}$$
This may not help though.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}
0&< \ln L_n=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} \ln{\left(2i-1\right)!!}\\&<\frac{\log(2n!)}{n^2}\sum_{i=2}^n\frac1i\\
&<\frac{\log(2n!)}{n^2}H_n\\
&<\frac{2n\log(2n)}{n^2}\left(\log n +\gamma +1\right)\to0
\end{align}$$
as $n\to\infty$
so that $\ln L_n\to 0$ and $L_n\to1$.

Comment: Great work! But you have a typo at the end, It should be, and $L\longrightarrow 1$

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn $L = 1$, $L_n \to 1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log({L_n})=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} \log\big[{\left(2i-1\right)!!}\Big]$$ Using Stirling approximation
$$\log\big[{\left(2i-1\right)!!}\Big]=i (\log (2 i)-1)+\frac{\log (2)}{2}-\frac{1}{24 i}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{i} \log\big[{\left(2i-1\right)!!}\Big]=-(1-\log(2))+\log(i)+\frac{\log (2)}{2
   i}-\frac{1}{24 i^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^4}\right)$$
$$\log({L_n})=\frac{1}{n^2}\Big[\frac{\log (2)}{2}  H_n-\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{24}+n (\log (2)-1)+\log (n!)+\frac{25}{24}-\frac{3 \log (2)}{2}+\cdots \Big]$$ Now, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers and factorial
$$\log(L_n)=\frac{\log (n)-2+\log (2)}{n}+\frac {a+b \log(n)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ where
$$a=\frac{25}{24}-\frac{\pi ^2}{144}+\frac{1}{2} \left(\gamma  \log (2)+\log \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{1+\log (2)}{2} $$ which, for sure, shows the limit $(\log(L_n) \to 0)$,and how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives a shortcut formula which is quite accurate as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 10 & 0.1295902 & 0.1298855 \\
 20 & 0.0934152 & 0.0934527 \\
 30 & 0.0741801 & 0.0741913 \\
 40 & 0.0621602 & 0.0621650 \\
 50 & 0.0538491 & 0.0538515 \\
 60 & 0.0477134 & 0.0477148 \\
 70 & 0.0429723 & 0.0429732 \\
 80 & 0.0391838 & 0.0391844 \\
 90 & 0.0360775 & 0.0360780 \\
 100 & 0.0334787 & 0.0334786
\end{array}
\right)$$